# Remove an HTML element from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following basic HTML:

```
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option></select>

<h1 id="firt">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

When the value `SECOND` is selected, a jQuery function should remove `<h2 id="second">Second</h2>`, so I made the following function:

```
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    tst = $(this).val()
    if (tst == 'second'){
        $('#second').remove()
    }
});
```

It works without any problem, the trouble is that my current function will remove that element definitively, instead, if the value `FIRST` is selected after `SECOND`, my html should go back to the initial state. How can I handle it? Should I use another function instead of `remove()` here?

Comment: Why not show / hide the elements as per need instead of removing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match the current value with *id* of the element to be shown:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    var tst = $(this).val();
    $('#first, #second').hide();
    $(`[id=${tst}]`).show()
});

$('.selector').trigger('change'); // trigger the event on page load to show the element by matching the value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option></select>

<h1 id="first">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

Comment: At last a simple parametric solution. All 8 other answers (!) rely on copy/pasting inefficient code N times.

Comment: Seems to be the shortest and most efficient way to go, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you should use hide when the selector is second and show other than selector second

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    tst = $(this).val()
    if (tst == 'second'){
        $('#second').hide();
    }
    else{
      $('#second').show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option>
<option value="third">Third</option>
</select>

<h1 id="firt">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can show and hide the element instead of removing it.
add common class as `heading` to both header and show it by default.

see below code

NOTE: correct the spelling of header with id="first"

```js
$(function(){
   $(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    $('.heading').show();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).hide()
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option></select>

<h1 class="heading" id="first">First</h1>
<h2 class="heading" id="second">Second</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is play with the css `display: none` rule:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    tst = $(this).val()
    if (tst == 'second'){
        $('#second').css({'display': 'none'})
    } else {
        $('#second').css({'display': 'inline'})
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option>
</select>

<h1 id="firt">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

It will make the element disappear without removing it completely from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

As @Umair mentioned, use `show`/`hide` for this.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    tst = $(this).val()
    $("#second, #first").show();
    if (tst == 'second'){
      $('#second').hide()
    } else {
      $('#first').hide()
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option></select>

<h1 id="first">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jquery show hide will be the better way to do

```js
$(document).on('change', '.selector', function() {
    tst = $(this).val()
    if(tst == 'second')
      $('#second').hide();
    else
      $('#second').show();  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="selector"><option value="first">FIRST</option><option value="second">SECOND</option></select>

<h1 id="firt">First</h1>
<h2 id="second">Second</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using change method we can manage hide/show in jQuery.divText set instance for selector according div id will hide & show

```
$(".selector").change(function() {
  let divText = $(this).val();

  if (divText === 'second') {
    $('#second').hide();
  } else {
    $('#second').show();
  };
});
```

Comment: divText set instance for selector according div id will hide & show. please let  me if you need additional detail.always helpful to community

Comment: Please update your answer by pressing edit button under your answer. Comment's section is not the right place for this.